# Python - Create copies of rows based on column value and increase date by number of iterations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe  in Python:

```
md
Out[94]: 
                     Key_ID      ronDt  multidays
0      Actuals-788-8AA-0001 2017-01-01        1.0
11     Actuals-788-8AA-0012 2017-01-09        1.0
20     Actuals-788-8AA-0021 2017-01-16        1.0
33     Actuals-788-8AA-0034 2017-01-25        1.0
36     Actuals-788-8AA-0037 2017-01-28        1.0
                    ...        ...        ...
55239  Actuals-789-8LY-0504 2020-02-12        1.0
55255  Actuals-788-T11-0001 2018-08-23        8.0
55257  Actuals-788-T11-0003 2018-09-01      543.0
55258  Actuals-788-T15-0001 2019-02-20      368.0
55259  Actuals-788-T15-0002 2020-02-24        2.0
```

I want to create an additional record for every multiday and increase the date (ronDt) by number of times that record was duplicated.
For example: 
row[0] would repeat one time with the new date reading 2017-01-02.
row[55255] would be repeated 8 times with the corresponding dates ranging from 2018-08-24 - 2018-08-31.

When I did this in VBA, I used loops, and in Alteryx I used multirow functions.  What is the best way to achieve this in Python?  Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick note: Please provide a proper sample data frame next time that people can have a chance to work on it and test it.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a Python newbie. I thought I did provide the data for working.  What is it that I you need me to provide?

Comment: No worries! Please check the solution and if it does not work, it would be helpful to provide dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to in pandas:

```
# get list of dates possible
df['datecol'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['ronDt'], periods=x['multidays'], freq='D'), 1)

# convert the list into new rows
df = df.explode('datecol').drop('ronDt', 1)

# rename the columns
df.rename(columns={'datecol': 'ronDt'}, inplace=True)

print(df)

                  Key_ID  multidays      ronDt
0   Actuals-788-8AA-0001        1.0 2017-01-01
1   Actuals-788-8AA-0012        1.0 2017-01-09
2   Actuals-788-8AA-0021        1.0 2017-01-16
3   Actuals-788-8AA-0034        1.0 2017-01-25
4   Actuals-788-8AA-0037        1.0 2017-01-28
..                   ...        ...        ...
8   Actuals-788-T15-0001      368.0 2020-02-20
8   Actuals-788-T15-0001      368.0 2020-02-21
8   Actuals-788-T15-0001      368.0 2020-02-22
9   Actuals-788-T15-0002        2.0 2020-02-24
9   Actuals-788-T15-0002        2.0 2020-02-25
```

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to .explode.
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: which pandas version you are using, ensure it should be `>=0.25`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get count of duplication for each row which corresponding to multidays col
df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'multidays'})

# Assume ronDt dtype is str so convert it to datetime object
# Then sum ronDt and multidays columns
df['ronDt_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ronDt']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['multidays'], unit='d')
```